# Javascript Regex - get div IDs from string html

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

Consider the following code:

```
const content = "<div id='x'><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2> <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p></div>"

let ids = content.match(/id='(.*?)'/g).map((val) => {
    return val.replace(/id='/g,'');
})
```

And when I do `console.log(ids)` - I get the output like this `'x\''` but I need only `'x'`. I'm wondering how to achive that result, I've tried by randomly changing regex symbols, because I don't know regex at all - and nothing seems to be working.

No jquery please. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you replacing only the first part of the ID attribute?

Comment: Regex isn't useful here. A more cleaner approach is to parse the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const content = "<div id='x'><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2> <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p></div>"

let ids = content.match(/id='(.*?)'/g).map((val) => {
    return val.replace(/id='/g,'').replace("'",'');
})

console.log(ids)
```

Comment: @GüvenAltuntaş This answer does indeedly what the OP is requested, but please don't say that it's the "right" answer. You can have the diameter of a circle by radius r using `let d = r * Math.sqrt(5 * 2 - 3 + 4 / 2 << 1 + 5 >> 4) / 3` too... This answer is of the same category.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

when you use dot "." it means everything but you are searching everithing but ' character

```
const content = "<div id='x'><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2> <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p></div>"

let ids = content.match(/id='([^' .*?])'/g).map((val) => {
    return val.replace(/id='([^' .*?])'/g,'$1');
})

console.log(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer explains an approach to getting DOM information from a string of HTML **without the need for Regular Expressions** (prone to bugs and errors when parsing DOM).

I am using a simple library (html-fragment) to create a DocumentFragment from the string of HTML. Since that string becomes a simple DOM tree in memory, you can `querySelectorAll` elements with the `id` attribute. You can then map the elements to get the array of ids.

```js
const content = "<div id='x'><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2> <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p></div>";

const fragment = HtmlFragment(content);
let ids = Array
  .from(fragment.querySelectorAll('[id]'))
  .map(el => el.id);

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html-fragment@1.1.0/lib/html-fragment.min.js"></script>
```